GCP Cloudrun multi-container-deployment reverse proxy issues
I have a web application composed of frontend (react + nginx reverse proxy) and backend (FastAPI) containers. I wanted to make life difficult and went the serverless route for this application using Cloudrun in a multi-container-deployment.
Background context (may or may not be relevant)
I've done all of the setup for securely authenticating internal end users. The stack is behind an internal application load balancer with NEGs and Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) - all of this is working fine. I'm able to hit the static IP assigned to my LB (10.196.XXX.XX), go through the oauth login flow, and reach the privately deployed application running on cloudrun in my browser.
However, when I try to execute certain functions in my frontend that call the backend API (which is a side car in a multi-container-deployment in the same cloud run) from my browser, I get errors that smell like NGINX isn't routing appropriately...
[Error] Could not connect to the server.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://127.0.0.1:8080/api/chat/ due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (chat, line 0)

As a reference, the nginx config below works for localhost in browser when running docker of a similar build locally.
nginx.conf
upstream backend {
    server llm-orc:8080;
}

server {
    listen 5173;
    server_name _;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 10000m;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s ipv6=off;
    resolver_timeout 10s;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
    gzip on;
  

    location ~ ^/(api) {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


}

I've read all of Google's documentation on Frontend Proxying using NGINX and GitHub examples for multi container cloud run deployment.
Here is the cloudrun service.yml and nginx.conf causing the error:
Service.yml
spec:
      containerConcurrency: 80
      timeoutSeconds: 550
      serviceAccountName: xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com
      containers:
      - name: frontend-ui
        image: us.gcr.io/ai-prj/frontend:latest
        ports:
        - name: http1
          containerPort: 5173
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 512Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-conf-secret
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/
        startupProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          timeoutSeconds: 240
          periodSeconds: 240
          failureThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: 5173
      - name: backend
        image: us.gcr.io/ai-prj/backend:latest
        env:
        - name: PORT
          value: '8080'
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 4000m
            memory: 16Gi
        startupProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 120
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /api/monitoring/health
            port: 8080
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-conf-secret
        secret:
          secretName: llm_nginx_config
          items:
          - key: latest
            path: default.conf

Nginx conf in the mounted secret
server {
    listen 5173;
    server_name _;

    gzip on;
  
    location ~ ^/(api) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location / {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}


And just incase it's relevant, the frontend code being executed in the ui causing the error in browser:
uiSlice.ts
export const ask = createAsyncThunk<any, any>('ask', async (question) => {
  const response = await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "/api/chat",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({query: question})
  });
  return response.data;
})


The only thing I haven't tried is to set an upstream / reverse proxy for the internal application LB at the 10.196.XXX.XX IP (rather than the 127.0.0.1 indicated in Google's documentation... and potentially add some ssl handling (tho that feels redundant given the cloud LB + IAP sitting in front of the cloudrun).
Also, there's a sort of routing abstraction happening from the cloudrun multi-container deployment + application LB that I'm not getting my head around -  I can successfully hit backend https://10.196.XXX.XX/api/ endpoints in browser/postman/curl directly as if they've been appropriately proxied, just not from functions called in the ui...
Any help / advice greatly appreciated!

Where do you have those [Error]? In your browser? On Cloud Run logs?

in the browser (developer tools console).

That was my fear. I don't know why NGINX do not proxy the connection but perform a redirect.

you were running into something similar @guillaumeblaquiere ? Only thing I get in Cloudrun logs is that it throws a temporary redirect: "POST /api/chat HTTP/1.1" 307 0 "https://10.196.XXX.XX/"
